# SQL - JOIN of two tables

Tags: sql, join

I have two tables:

[image]

I am trying to answer this question:

**Write a query that returns the cities and the number of employees associated with them. Show only cities where the average age of employees is greater than 25. Sort the table by the names of the cities in ascending order.**

My answer is:

```
SELECT emp.Name, AVG(emp.Age), emp.id, city_emp.city
FROM Emp_det emp JOIN CityWorkers city_emp
ON emp.id = city_emp.id
GROUP BY city_emp.city
HAVING AVG(EMP.Age) > 25 
ORDER BY city_emp.city
```

But this is inncorrect.
Can you help me please?

Comment: You SELECT too many columns. Remove a couple of them. (You typically GROUP BY the same columns as you SELECT, except those who are arguments to set functions.)

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT COUNT(emp.id) AS num_of_emp, 
   AVG(emp.Age) AS AVG_age, 
   city_emp.city
  FROM Emp_det emp JOIN CityWorkers city_emp
  ON emp.id = city_emp.id
  GROUP BY city_emp.city
  HAVING AVG(EMP.Age) > 25 
  ORDER BY city_emp.city
```

Comment: code-only answers are discouraged. We should rather explain the challenge, and how our solution tackles it.